# how to return a pointer type in runtime component?

Tags: c#, c++, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime

**question description**

I have a public api in a runtime component, I hope that its public member can return a `pointer type`, such as:

```
namespace WinRt
{
    public value struct struct_instance_t{};

    class classTest
    {
        struct_instanst_t* RuntimeApi() {
            return otherCApi(); //  other_namespace::struct_instanst_t* otherCApi()
        }
    };
}
```

**My question**

It has a compile error, like:

```
error C3992: 'vadNew': signature of public member contains invalid type 'WinRt::struct_instance_t *'
```

What should I do?

whether there is a type or way instead the pointer?

Comment: Use a `ref struct` if you want return-by-reference semantics.

Comment: Possible duplicate of.... 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356851/in-c-how-do-i-invoke-a-dll-function-that-returns-an-unmanaged-structure-contai

Answer (score 0):

How about...

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute("YourC++.dll", EntryPoint="otherCApi")]
public static extern  System.IntPtr otherCApi() ;

public static struct_instance_t RuntimeApi() {
   IntPtr ptr = otherCApi();
   return (struct_instanst_t)(Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, typeof(struct_instanst_t));
}
```