# Call third party dll, parameters have out an array but passing an object C#.NET 2.0

Tags: c#

Call an older third party dll, passing parameters require an object, but the same parameter output an array, how to accomplish this? Thank you?

```
Array ItemValues = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int), 1);
            Array ItemServerErrors = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int), 1);

            Array ItemQuality = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int), 1);
            Array ItemtimeStamp = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(DateTime), 1); 


            myGroup.SyncRead(1, 1, ref RandomMoneyHandler, ref ItemValues, out ItemServerErrors, out ItemQuality, out ItemtimeStamp);
```

But QualityObject and TimeStampObject indeed returns an array from VB example

```
 Dim ItemCount As Short = 1
    Dim ItemServerHandles(1) As Integer
    Dim ItemValues As Array
    Dim ItemServerErrors As Array
    Dim ItemQuality As Array
    Dim ItemTimeStamp As Array

    ItemServerHandles(1) = myItem.ServerHandle

    myGroup.SyncRead(OPCAutomation.OPCDataSource.OPCCache, ItemCount, ItemServerHandles, ItemValues, ItemServerErrors, ItemQuality, ItemTimeStamp)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wb7zM.jpg)

**What are the syntax for this function call in C#?**

Comment: `ItemValues` should be `out`, not `ref`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In C#, how do I invoke a DLL function that returns an unmanaged structure containing a string pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356851/in-c-how-do-i-invoke-a-dll-function-that-returns-an-unmanaged-structure-contai)

Answer (score 0):

Its clear from image you shared

**SyncRead()** excepts `ItemValues` as `out` parameter , you are passing it as `ref`

Try changing your code from

```
 myGroup.SyncRead(1, 1, ref RandomMoneyHandler, ref ItemValues, out ItemServerErrors, out ItemQuality, out ItemtimeStamp);
```

to

```
 myGroup.SyncRead(1, 1, ref RandomMoneyHandler, out ItemValues, out ItemServerErrors, out ItemQuality, out ItemtimeStamp);
```